# Z3-Python as SAT solver does not give right results

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, sat, satisfiability

I am trying to use Z3 (in Python) as a SAT solver, but the results are unexpected.

First, imagine I want to get a model for the following formula:

```
from z3 import *

c_0 = Bool('c_0')
c_1 = Bool('c_1')
c_2 = Bool('c_2')
c_3 = Bool('c_3')

sss = Solver()
negations = And(Not(c_0), Not(c_1), Not(c_2), Not(c_3))
sss.add(Not(negations))
print(sss.check())
print(sss.model())
```

So I get `sat`, with the model `[c_0 = True, c_3 = False, c_1 = False, c_2 = False]`, which holds the formula (I do not know why the variable assignments are given in that order).

But now, I add `And(Not(c_1), Not(c_2), Not(c_3))` to the formula (no need to understand why). Then I get the result `unsat`, which makes no sense. The result should be `sat`, for instance, with the model `[c_0 = True, c_1 = False, c_2 = True, c_3 = False]`.

Here is the code:

```
added_negations = And(Not(c_1), Not(c_2), Not(c_3))
new_Negations = And(negations, Not(added_negations))

ss = Solver()
ss.add(new_Negations)
print(new_Negations)
print(ss.check())
```

Any help? I tested this using explicit `Exists(c_0,c_1...)` but the result is the same.

I MADE A MISTAKE!!!

There is a negation missing in `new_Negations = And(negations, Not(added_negations))`. Correctly: `new_Negations = And(Not(negations), Not(added_negations))`

Correcting this, the result is again `sat`, concretely, with a model: `[c_0 = False, c_3 = False, c_1 = True, c_2 = False]`

Comment: I just realized I made a mistake. The answer is cool anyway, because using it, I would have not forgotten a negation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created two solvers, one called `ss`, the other called `sss`. They’re independent. If you want to add new clauses, just use the existing solver, do not create a new one.

Comment: Indeed, I will accept this as answer, because it would have made me not to make the mistake! So if I add new clauses, they are conjuncted by AND, right?

Comment: Yes. Each time you call `add`, you’re adding a new conjunct.